# Disambiguate the [DRM]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The [drm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drm) seems to have multiple definitions in its information [section](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/drm/info):

1. Digital Rights Management
2. Direct Rendering Manager

The second was edited into the tag info and approved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5039368/revisions).

There are  422 questions most of which deal with the former while a simple search for "Direct Rendering Manager" with DRM tag gives a couple of old posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdrm%5D++Direct+Rendering+Manager&mixed=0).

Are both meanings for the same tag necessary?

I suggest having a separate tag like [direct-rendering-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/direct-rendering-manager) if they are on topic.

Comment: Bad idea, rolled back.

Comment: Digital *Restrictions* Management is the more accurate term, because it is what it actually is: https://www.fsf.org/campaigns/drm.html

Comment: @SargeBorsch We're not activists here. "Digital Rights Management" is the term that most people use and recognise, and as such, should be the one that we use.

Comment: @SargeBorsch He's got a whole list of those [here](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/words-to-avoid.html). Digital Restrictions Management is one of the more catchy ones.

Comment: @HansPassant, make it an answer maybe?

Comment: @SargeBorsch: that would be appropriate for the tag wiki for whatever we end up naming it.  But not for the tag name.